# Securing multi core solr/jetty server with OpenSSL/https

Tags: ssl, solr, openssl, jetty

I have a multi core solr instance running on a server with Jetty and I'm working on securing the backend. I have configured Jetty to use https protocol and everything works fine when I submit a /select to solr while not using any shards like:

```
https://localhost:7450/solr/core0/select?indent=true&rows=10&start=0&q=*:*
```

I get my search results back and all is good.

But when I want to search across all shards:

```
https://localhost:7450/solr/core0/select?indent=true&rows=10&start=0&q=*:*&shards=localhost:7450/solr/core0,localhost:7450/solr/core1,...
```

I get the below exception. I'm guessing I need to configure solr itself somehow so it sends/receives requests via https protocol to other shards but I'm out of luck after searching Google for hours.

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:275)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector$SslConnection.run(SslSocketConnector.java:713)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server localhost failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:472)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:249)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler$1.call(HttpShardHandler.java:103)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:651)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:676)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.httpclient.ProtocolException: The server localhost failed to respond with a valid HTTP response
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1987)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:419)
    ... 8 more
```

I'm using Solr 3.6 and Jetty 6.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: which solr version are you using? Can you disable https on your shards and only expose one solr server to the user?

Comment: The problem is that https currently is NOT enabled on shards and I'm looking to a way to enable it. 

I added solr and jetty version info with some more details to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the URL scheme used for shard calls in solrconfig.xml for core0:

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
  <!-- other params go here -->
  <shardHandlerFactory class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <str name="urlScheme">https://</str>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
</requestHandler>
```

From looking at the source, it appears this works for Solr 3.6.0 and higher. I'm still using Solr 3.4.0, though, so I haven't tried it myself.

Reference: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#Configuration_of_Shard_Handlers_for_Distributed_searches

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working on getting this setup for myself, but it appears that the support has been added in Solr 4.7  See the original bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3854